# Invoke-WebRequest login to web site

Tags: powershell, authentication, webrequest

What I am attempting is to use Powershells **Invoke-WebRequest** Cmdlet to login to a web site. Here's my code:

```
$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.franklinamerican.com/ext/general?npage=home -SessionVariable franklin

$form = $login.Forms[0]

$form.Fields["userName"] = "username123"
$form.Fields["brokerPassword"] = "password456"

$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.franklinamerican.com/ext/general?npage=home -WebSession $franklin -Method POST -Body $form.Fields

$login.StatusDescription
```

I receive an 'OK' from the StatusDescription regardless of whether the credentials are correct, which seems odd and confusing. What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks everyone

edit: Results of calling $login.InputFields

[1]: image of https://i.stack.imgur.com/n52XO.png

Comment: Also how would I go about getting IE to open and show the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing from interpreting the results is that `$login.StatusDescription` refers to the *HTTP Status* which in this case is likely HTTP status code 200, which translates to "OK".

That is unrelated to the web site's (forms-based) authentication. You're missing something that is needed by the form. Look at `$login.Content` and see if the web site gave you a more specific error in the HTML that you can use.

Comment: Should I be referencing the fields by Id or Name? Also I did what you said and it looks like I may have to click() the submit button. Just not sure how exactly to do that